# How to pass command line arguments into the implementation js file in gauge project?

Tags: gauge, getgauge, jsgauge

I am using gauge-js for running puppeteer scripts and I am trying to pass in custom argument from command lines.

while I am running my gauge run spec command to run the test cases I want to pass in any custom argument like gauge run spec --username=test and read that value inside my implementation files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass custom arguments to Gauge. However, you can use environment variables to pass any additional information you need in your implementation files.

For example, you can run gauge as 
(on mac/*nix)

```
username=test gauge run spec
```

or 
(on windows)

```
set username=test
gauge run specs
```

and use the environment variable in your implementation file using `process.env.username`.

You can additionally set the variable in the .property files in the `env` folder. These get picked up as environment variables as well.